# No route matches {:action=>"upvote", :controller=>"comments", :post_id=>#<Comment id: 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

There is like button for comments. You should be able to like a comment on Post's show page(with index of comments for that specific Post) or on comment's show page

This error appears when I visit this URL:

> .../posts/1/comments/1

```
No route matches {:action=>"upvote", :controller=>"comments", :post_id=>#<Comment id: 1, title: "This is kinda good!", content: "Testing comment", user_id: 1, post_id: 1, created_at: "2014-04-09 21:35:19", updated_at: "2014-04-09 21:35:19">, :id=>nil, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

When I visit to see a list of comments and like buttons:

> .../posts/1/

Similar error appears, but with

```
... #<Comment id: nil, title: nil, content: nil, user_id: nil ...
```

---

like button

```
<%= link_to "Like", like_post_comment_path(@comment), method: :put, :remote => true %>
```

routes

```
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments do
      member do
        put "like", to: "comments#upvote"
        put "dislike", to: "comments#downvote"
      end
    end
  end
```

comments_controller

```
def upvote
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.liked_by current_user
    render "update_likes"
  end
```

when I run rake routes

```
like_post_comment PUT      /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/like(.:format)        comments#upvote                                                                          
dislike_post_comment PUT      /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/dislike(.:format)     comments#downvote
```

Comment: Run rake routes and show us the results.

Comment: I edited the post. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<%= link_to "Like", like_post_comment_path(@comment), method: :put, :remote => true %>
```

To

```
<%= link_to "Like", like_post_comment_path(@comment.post_id, @comment), method: :put, :remote => true %>
```

As per your route:

```
like_post_comment PUT      /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/like(.:format)        comments#upvote
```

you need both `:post_id` and `:id` in the route.

Answer (score 0):

The route is `like_post_comment PUT      /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/like(.:format)        comments#upvote`, which means it expects a `:post_id` and `:id` parameter, so something like this:

```
<%= link_to "Like", like_post_comment_path(:id => @comment.id, :post_id => @post.id), method: :put, :remote => true %>
```